# Azure instance stuck on "waiting for status"

Tags: azure

My small Microsoft Azure site that uses just one instance was down for a few hours today, failing to respond to any requests.  I hadn't deployed anything new in weeks.  Looking at the Azure dashboard, my Cloud Service did NOT have a green check box that said Running.  Clicking on the Cloud Service and then on the Instances tab, I could see that Status for my one instance just said "Waiting for status".  There were a couple options available at the bottom, "Reboot" and "Reimage".  I tried both.  It would spend a couple minutes doing the Reboot or Reimage, and then when it was complete, the status would go right back to saying "Waiting for Status" and the site still didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stopped working"? What happened when you browsed to the site?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't more specific.  The site was just stalled, not responding to any requests, eventually timing out.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Next time you can troubleshoot using the steps at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally fixed it for me was to go back and do another Publish from Visual Studio.  I'm afraid I don't understand for sure why that worked. I'm guessing that my site got deployed to a different server that way, and the server that it had been on before was having problems.  But it worked and the site came right back up after Publishing completed.